# Approximating $\mathcal X \subset \mathbb R^n$ with the union of disjoint hyperrectangles

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, algorithms, convex-analysis, approximation

Let $\mathcal X$ be a bounded subset of $R^n$ that is generated by a set of linear inequalities. For example, let ${\bf x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5)^\intercal \in \mathcal X$ iff
\begin{align*}
0 &< x_1 < x_2 < x_4 < x_5 < 1 \\
0 &< x_1 < x_3 < 1.
\end{align*}

I want to find an algorithm that generates a set of $L$ disjoint hyperrectangles, denoted $R_1, \ldots R_L$ such that
$$\mathcal X \approx \bigcup_{\ell=1}^L R_\ell.$$

The algorithm must have the properties:

1. $\bigcup_{\ell=1}^L R_\ell$ is a strict subset of $\mathcal X$
2. The approximation improves (under Lesbesgue measure $
   \lambda$) as $L$ increases,
   $$\lim_{L\rightarrow\infty} \lambda\left(\left\{\mathcal X - \bigcup_{\ell=1}^L R_\ell\right\}\right) = 0$$
3. The hyperrectangles must be disjoint and must be axis aligned.

---

The optimal solution for each $L$ would minimize the Lesbesgue measure of the set $\mathcal X -\bigcup_{\ell=1}^L R_\ell$. I can sense that an optimal solution for this problem, in general, is going to be very difficult to find. Rather, I am looking for a "reasonably good" (possibly greedy) solution which can be obtained fairly quickly.

**Note:** Although I would like to have some *broad* control over the number of rectangles in the approximation, the algorithm doesn't need to return *exactly* $L$ boxes.

---

#### My approach so far

My approach right now consists of

1. Partitioning the unconstrained space into $L = M^n$ equidistant, same-size hyperrectangles (by partitioning each dimension into $M$ equally sized intervals).
2. Checking to see if each vertex of each hyperrectangle is completely contained in $\mathcal X$.

This approach meets my minimum-criteria, but it is far from optimal, in the sense that the same approximation can be achieved with many fewer rectangles. I feel that the next step would be to try to combine the rectangles in some way, but I just don't have good enough intuition in high-dimensions to figure out a good way of doing this.

Comment: What do you do if the set has no interior?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean, that's the easiest case. The algorithm returns the $\emptyset$ which is a perfect approximation (with respect to Lesbesgue measure).

Comment: You could use the Tarski-Seidelberg algorithm to find a maximal hyperrectangle inside $\cal X$. If you treat the T-S algorithm as a black box, that will help with the number of iterations in your code, but the T-S algorithm doesn't scale well and there aren't very many off-the-shelf implementations. In your application, is $\cal X$ a one-off or does it evolve in time? If the latter, then an algorithm that patches a previous result to get the next one might be useful.

Comment: @RobArthan I would say that you can view $\mathcal X$ as a one-off for now. It's not like we'll be running this several times a day, but I'm looking for an approach which is general enough to be applied to different constrained spaces. Either way, $\mathcal X$ does not evolve in time. Thanks, I'll look into the TS algorithm. Do you think it is possible to apply this algorithm repeatedly $(e.g., find $R_1$ then find $R_2$ which is the maximal hyperrectangel in $\mathcal X - R_1$ etc.)?

Comment: Yes, you could intersect $\cal X$ with the complement of the set of hyperrectangles you have found already and so apply the algorithm repeatedly. Aside: I am ignorant about how to calculate the volume of a set like $\cal X$, so I don't know how you can determine how good the successive approximations are.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you, that is an interesting approach. I have an approach based on recursive partitioning that is working, but what your recommend sounds like it might be close to optimal for any given $L$ (optimal at each step, but greedy). I'll have to look into T-S. If you want to type up a response, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Aside: I can approximate the volume of the space with Monte Carlo. This may be problematic in truly high dimensions, but it's feasible for my applications.

Comment: You know your problem better than me. I suggest you look into Tarski-Seidelberg and see how practical it is for you and perhaps answer your own question when you've assessed it. I don't want to give an answer implying that T-S is suitable when I don't have any evidence for its efficiency on your problem. Best of luck!

Comment: @RobArthan Can you suggest a (somewhat accessible) reference for your claim "You could use the Tarski-Seidelberg algorithm to find a maximal hyperrectangle inside".

Comment: I don't know how accessible you'll find them but the books *Real Algebraic Geometry* and *Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry* by Roy et al. are my goto resource on this. (Full references can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_algebraic_geometry).) You can write down a first order formula that asserts that $2^n$ vectors comprise the vertices of a maximal hyperrectangle and you should be able to extract the answer from a quantifier-free equivalent of that formula, although that might actually require some heuristics, if it's not unique.

Comment: On a practical level, you could look into a tool like QEPCAD that implements T-S. It may be that the facilities it provides for working with cylindrical algebraic decompositions are of more use to you than just the quantifier-elimination.